# Partially pivot a table based on certain conditions?

Tags: oracle

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to create this view, but here it's what I have now:

```
 ITEM     CODE       AGE      TYPE      INFO
------  --------  --------  --------  --------
1         A10        NEW       4        INFO A10           
2         B12        NEW       4        INFO B12
3         B15        NONE      4        INFO B15 
4         T11        NEW       4        INFO T11
4         T14        OLD       3        INFO T14 
4         T15        OLD       2        INFO T15
5         R01        OLD       4        INFO R01
5         R71        OLD       4        INFO R71
5         R55        OLD       3        INFO R55
5         R30        OLD       2        INFO R30
```

What I want to do is:

- Remove the duplicate values on the column "ITEM";
- Make those Rows removed become columns based on:

  - If at least one o the itens has AGE = 'NEW' than keep it as the main column 'CODE'
  - If there is no AGE = 'NEW', get the first row as the main column 'CODE', doesn't matter which one it is.
- The AGE, TYPE and INFO Columns will be based on the info of the main column 'CODE'
- The number of new columns CODES (CODE_2, CODE_3,...) are fixed in 10

> ```
> ITEM     CODE     CODE_2    CODE_3    CODE_4     AGE       TYPE     INFO
> ------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  -------- --------
> 1         A10         -          -          -      NEW       4      INFO A10
> 2         B12         -          -          -      NEW       4      INFO B12
> 3         B15         -          -          -      NEW       4      INFO B15
> 4         T11        T14        T15         -      NONE      4      INFO T11
> 5         R01        R71        R55        R30     OLD       4      INFO R01
> ```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: why `AGE` in 3rd line are `NEW` in result? I think it should be `NONE`. and the next question is: Are it should be view with dynamic count of columns? Or it may be created with 10 columns (`code_...`) and additional 4 ?

Comment: @MichaelPiankov You are right. It was supposed to be NONE on the fourth line and old on the fifth. The idea is to create a static number of code columns (CODE,CODE_1,....CODE_9).

Answer (score 0):

As you say about creation of view I suppose that you need stable set of columns. IN that case you my use something like:

```
with s (item, code, age, type, info) as 
(select 1, 'A10', 'NEW', 4, 'INFO A10'  from dual union all
select 2, 'B12', 'NEW', 4, 'INFO B12'  from dual union all
select 3, 'B15', 'NONE', 4, 'INFO B15'  from dual union all
select 4, 'T11', 'NEW', 4, 'INFO T11'  from dual union all
select 4, 'T14', 'OLD', 3, 'INFO T14'  from dual union all
select 4, 'T15', 'OLD', 2, 'INFO T15'  from dual union all
select 5, 'R01', 'OLD', 4, 'INFO R01'  from dual union all
select 5, 'R71', 'OLD', 4, 'INFO R71 '  from dual union all
select 5, 'R55', 'OLD', 3, 'INFO R55'  from dual union all
select 5, 'R30', 'OLD', 2, 'INFO R30'  from dual 
)
select item,
       max(code)as CODE,
       max(code_2) as CODE_2,
       max(code_3) as CODE_3,
       max(code_4) as CODE_4,
       max(code_5) as CODE_5,
       max(code_6) as CODE_6,
       max(code_7) as CODE_7,
       max(code_8) as CODE_8,
       max(code_9) as CODE_9,
       max(code_10) as CODE_10,
       max(age)  as age,
       max(type)  as type,
       max(info)  as info
FROM (
select item, 
       decode(code_name,1,code) as code,
       decode(code_name,2,code) as code_2,
       decode(code_name,3,code) as code_3,
       decode(code_name,4,code) as code_4,
       decode(code_name,5,code) as code_5,
       decode(code_name,6,code) as code_6,
       decode(code_name,7,code) as code_7,
       decode(code_name,8,code) as code_8,
       decode(code_name,9,code) as code_9,
       decode(code_name,10,code) as code_10,
       decode(code_name,1,age) as age,
       decode(code_name,1,type) as type,
       decode(code_name,1,info) as info
from (select s.*,
       row_number() over (partition by item order by decode(age,'NEW',0,1),CODE) as code_name
  from s))
  group by item;
```